# Missing or skipped ICMP_Seq In AIX Ping

Tags: networking, ping, telnet, aix

I noticed an intermittent slow response on the ping from my application server to my database server.   So to diagnose, I tested using a standard ping and Telnet tests.

For the telnet tests, it was able to connect. However some telnet took longer to connect than others.

For the ping, I noticed that I am missing a lot of  icmp_seq. It was skipping occasionally. On the other server, it was communicating very sequentially.

But for the app to web and app to app, there were no skipped items.  From the app to DB there is.

Anyone have any idea on what is happening ?

Just to add, the database response was very intermittent as well. Sometimes slow. The application server and database are on different network segments as well.

What can we look at ?

Comment: What OS is on your database server?

Comment: Aix as well. Thanks. The icmp_seq on the ping from app server to database server skips a lot.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you performed? How is the state of the network between these servers? How is the load on the servers? Are there any errors in commonly used logs?

Comment: The servers are newly commissioned servers with no usage at all. We did thread dumps in the java application to check the slow response and found out that database response is slow.

Comment: So we did telnet and ping tests. Telnet takes time to connect intermittently. Same with the skipped icmp_seq

Comment: What are skipped icmp_seq symptoms of. ? I tried the ping from app1 to app2 and there were no issues.

Comment: @grassbl8d. You have packet loss somewhere in the network between your two servers. You will need to use basic troubleshooting to identify where your packets are getting lost. Ping the various network hops between Server A and B and see where the problem is being introduced.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds an awful lot like you have a duplex mismatch or congestion somewhere in the network between the app and the DB. Have you tried doing a **traceroute** between the 2 endpoint or are they in the same IP subnet? Can you elaborate on the **type** of network (e.g. LAN,LeaseLine) and available network-bandwidths between the app and the DB?

Comment: What do you mean duplex mismatch ? When does this occur ? I'll try traceroute. This is LAN and on different subnets. App and DB are on different subnets. Thanks

Comment: Is this related to my missing ICMP_SEQ during ping ? Thanks.